# Android fragment replace(...) on thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

Can someone explain me why replacing fragment on thread causes sometimes blank space instead of showing the fragment on screen?

```
public void swapFragment(final CustomFragment fragment) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getName());
            ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());

            ft.commit();
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Let me explain what is happening:

1) I have no fragment added inside my container.

2) I'm adding fragment **A** using this method - its working

3) Then I'm using this method to swap actual fragment **A** with my fragment **B** - its working

4) But when I'm trying to swap it with new instance (**!!!**) of fragment ***A*** it leaves blank space

I know that i can do it on main thread, but this is just an example. I'm dealing with different issue, but my issue is more complex to explain.

## EDIT :

at point 4) I placed wrong fragment - it was ment to be "*fragment A*"

Answer (score 2):

You are swapping same Fragment **B** with its new instance.

> Swapping operation will work only when source and destination
>   fragments are of different classes.

I can defer this from answers [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6266144/1994950) and question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14959198/1994950)

So, workaround would be :

1. Check if same fragment class is already added (`isAdded()`) or not, if not then `swap()` else use `remove()` and `add()` operation

   ```
   public void swapFragment(final CustomFragment fragment) {

   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           if(!fragment.isAdded()) {
               ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getName());
               ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());

               ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

           } else {
               ft.remove(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
               ft.add(fragment);
               ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());

               ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

       }
   }).start();
   ```

   }
2. Check if same fragment class is already added (`isAdded()`) then update its UI content, else `swap()`

   ```
   public void swapFragment(final CustomFragment fragment) {

   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           if(!fragment.isAdded()) {
               ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getName());
               ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());

               ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
           } else {
               // logic to update UI of same instance
           }
       }
   }).start();
   ```

   }

Still, exact solution is awaited for this question :)

Hope this will help you